# Map within a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a drodown with a grouping on it and I was able to achieve that using static code like this

```
      <li className="dropdown-submenu">
          <a tabindex="-1" href="#" className="dropdown-link">Multi Level</a>
          <ul className="dropdown-menu" id="Status">
               <li class="dropdown-item">
                   <a className="dropdown-link" href="#" id="" aria-label="">Multi Children</a>
               </li>
               <li class="dropdown-item">
                 <a className="dropdown-link" href="#" id="" aria-label="">Multi Children</a>
               </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

but when I try to add a more dynamic value to it using a map somehow the inner map is not getting accepted

```
<li className="dropdown-submenu">
 {props.DropDownData.Group.map(e =>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" className="dropdown-link">{e.GroupViewName}</a>
     { e.GroupViewMembers.map(x => 
         <ul className="dropdown-menu" id="Status">
            <li class="dropdown-item">
              <a className="dropdown-link" href="#" id="" aria-label="">{x.Title}</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
     )}

 )}
 </li>
```

Here is the structure of my data

[image]

Comment: What you posted isn't even syntactically valid. Also, you can't have an expression with multiple consecutive JSX elements (in your case an anchor tag and a bunch of unordered lists), wrap the output in a div or a `React.Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I believe you'll need to return the second map nested...

```
`<li className="dropdown-submenu">
 {props.DropDownData.Group.map(e =>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" className="dropdown-link">{e.GroupViewName}</a>
     { return e.GroupViewMembers.map(x => 
         <ul className="dropdown-menu" id="Status">
            <li class="dropdown-item">
              <a className="dropdown-link" href="#" id="" aria-label="">{x.Title}</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
     )}

 )}
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

A map operator has to return one value, it can't return several JSX elements. You can wrap multiple elements in a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). Fragments do not get inserted into the DOM but group elements.

```
<li className="dropdown-submenu">
 {props.DropDownData.Group.map(e =>
  <Fragment>
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" className="dropdown-link">{e.GroupViewName}</a>
       { e.GroupViewMembers.map(x => 
           <ul className="dropdown-menu" id="Status">
              <li class="dropdown-item">
                <a className="dropdown-link" href="#" id="" aria-label="">{x.Title}</a>   
              </li>
           </ul>
       )}
  </Fragment>
  )}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to get the value via array index, like this:

```html
<li className="dropdown-submenu">
  {props.DropDownData.Group.map(e, i =>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" className="dropdown-link">{e.GroupViewName}</a>
  { DropDownData.Group[i].GroupViewMembers.map(x =>
  <ul className="dropdown-menu" id="Status">
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a className="dropdown-link" href="#" id="" aria-label="">{x.Title}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  )}

  )}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks but using index is not needed on this.

Answer (score 0):

The inner map isn't syntactically the same as your static code.  The static code has many titles inside a single `ul` element.  Your map code has a `ul` and `li` element for each title.

I think you want something more like:

```
<ul className="dropdown-menu" id="Status">
{ e.GroupViewMembers.map(x => 
   <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a className="dropdown-link" href="#" id="" aria-label="">
         {x.Title}
      </a> 
   </li>
)}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I started from scract and recode everything up. Now everything is working properly.

```
 <ul className="dropdown-menu multi-level" id="dropdown-main">
                            {props.DropDownData.Group.map(e =>
                                <li className="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" className="dropdown-link">{e.GroupViewName}</a>
                                    <ul className="dropdown-menu" id="Status">

                                        {e.GroupViewMembers.map(x =>
                                            <li class="dropdown-item">
                                                <a className="dropdown-link" href="#" id="" aria-label="">{x.Title}</a>
                                            </li>
                                        )}
                                    </ul>

                                </li>

                            )}

                        </ul>
```